# Given a mathematically linked 2D Array (NxM), Can a log(N)log(M) search algorithm be created

Tags: algorithm, search

I have generated this 2D Array (NxM) where all columns, rows, and diagonals can be generated by an equation. I just want to know if I can create a search algorithm where it run in log(N)log(M)?

This 2D Array is infinite as well, just showing the first 10 rows/10 columns

The equation used is z = 2*d*x - 2*x*y - y^2, d=22 for this case and the top axis is x, the side axis declining is y. so (1,1) = 41, (2,2) = 76. The goal is to find z, duplicate values should focus on smallest x, though unique values are always going to be the focus of the search.

Note all the rows and columns and diagonals will produce unique equations that will carry the row, column or diagonal to infinity.

[image: Mathematically Generated Grid]

Comment: So, why you can't use the equation to locate the element?

Comment: It uses the coordinates, value is calculated

Comment: Where is the (0, 0) coordinate in your table? In bottom left or in top left corner? Also, as was said, you can try to solve your equation (if it's simple enough) to find coordinates that give you needed value. Can you please share your equation?

Comment: There are duplicates in your example. I see -4 twice. 20 is in there 3 times. What criteria are you searching for? What should it do with duplicates?

Comment: The value to be searched for will never be a duplicate, ie 43. Its a specific case which should always be unique within a range

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is increasing along the columns and decreasing along the rows.  If so then the answer will be along a diagonal zigzag path with no other obvious structure.

Unless there is more structure to the equations, I don't think you can do better than to try to find that path.  That algorithm is `O(n+m)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if

```
z = 2*d*x - 2*x*y - y^2, d=22
```

Then given search target z' you can just solve

```
z' = 2dx - 2xy - y^2
z' + y^2 = 2x(d - y)
x = (1/2) (z' + y^2) / (d - y)
```

Additional constraints are that x, y are integers greater than zero. That immediately tells you that y will be an integer from 1 to d - 1 (assuming d is an integer) and y must have the same parity as z (either both are even, or both are odd).

In fact, if you can choose y = d - 1 by the above criteria, then x = (1/2) (z' + d^2 - 2d + 1) is a solution; in your example, consider d = 22 and z' = 103. Then y = 21, x = 272 and the solution checks out (plug into your original equation). If you can't choose d - 1 due to the parity issue, it seems like the solution won't be as neat. I guess this makes sense since there should be problems with no integer solutions, e.g., d = 1 and z' = 1, d = 2 and z' = 2, etc. There might be more shortcuts.

Comment: Well you just solved the case which is the worse case I was trying to avoid. Back to the 43 example. The answer I want to find is x=2,y=5. x=21 and y=242 is another answer, but not the case I want to find.